# Add User Input to a CSV file without importing the module

Tags: python

I was given a task to write a student database and I cannot use any libraries. One of the options is to add a new student, and I was wondering if there's a way to append that info without using the module? I searched up and down on google and I can't seem to find anything. I'm new to python so I'm sorry if it's a stupid question. Below is the function I would love to use in that project.

```
from csv import writer

def add_new():

    new = [x for x in input("New student data: ").split()]
    with open("students.csv","a", newline="") as f:
        writer_object = writer(f)
        writer_object.writerow(new)
        f.close()
    
add_new()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the data to the file as follows using only standard library (however in this case there is no validation of the user input):

```
def add_new():
    new = input("New student data: ")
    with open("students.csv","a", newline="") as f:
        f.write(new)

add_new()
```

Please note that because you are (correctly) using the "with" context handler, there is no more need for f.close(). The file closes automatically.

Comment: I tried doing exactly that before, but because I was writing it with spaces it didn't want to work. After your answer I tried adding .replace(" ", ",") to the input and now it works well. It seems the problem was that the input had to be, for example: sam,smith, with only commas seperating the words, since "write" only operates on string. Thank you for your answer, it made me rethink my plan again.

Comment: glad that I could help, would you mind to mark the question as solved then?